# Qt QML dropdown list like in HTML

Tags: qt, drop-down-menu, qt-creator, qml

Simple thing, but can't get find it. I want a simple dropdown selection box with a couple of selections. Like in HTML

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

what is the code for QML for that ?

Comment: As strange as it may seems, there is no "builtin" combobox in QML. You have to build it yourself using other primitives. There are plenty of examples, though.

Comment: maybe something like this: https://github.com/SC-One/DropDownInputQML , it's like tags in stack when asking question(look at bottom of the page)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a simple example that could maybe be used as a starting point:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width:400;
    height: 400;

    Rectangle {
            id:comboBox
            property variant items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
            property alias selectedItem: chosenItemText.text;
            property alias selectedIndex: listView.currentIndex;
            signal comboClicked;
            width: 100;
            height: 30;
            z: 100;
            smooth:true;

            Rectangle {
                id:chosenItem
                radius:4;
                width:parent.width;
                height:comboBox.height;
                color: "lightsteelblue"
                smooth:true;
                Text {
                    anchors.top: parent.top;
                    anchors.left: parent.left;
                    anchors.margins: 8;
                    id:chosenItemText
                    text:comboBox.items[0];
                    font.family: "Arial"
                    font.pointSize: 14;
                    smooth:true
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        comboBox.state = comboBox.state==="dropDown"?"":"dropDown"
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id:dropDown
                width:comboBox.width;
                height:0;
                clip:true;
                radius:4;
                anchors.top: chosenItem.bottom;
                anchors.margins: 2;
                color: "lightgray"

                ListView {
                    id:listView
                    height:500;
                    model: comboBox.items
                    currentIndex: 0
                    delegate: Item{
                        width:comboBox.width;
                        height: comboBox.height;

                        Text {
                            text: modelData
                            anchors.top: parent.top;
                            anchors.left: parent.left;
                            anchors.margins: 5;

                        }
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent;
                            onClicked: {
                                comboBox.state = ""
                                var prevSelection = chosenItemText.text
                                chosenItemText.text = modelData
                                if(chosenItemText.text != prevSelection){
                                    comboBox.comboClicked();
                                }
                                listView.currentIndex = index;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Component {
                id: highlight
                Rectangle {
                    width:comboBox.width;
                    height:comboBox.height;
                    color: "red";
                    radius: 4
                }
            }

            states: State {
                name: "dropDown";
                PropertyChanges { target: dropDown; height:40*comboBox.items.length }
            }

            transitions: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { target: dropDown; properties: "height"; easing.type: Easing.OutExpo; duration: 1000 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: got just one weird thing, i've got a couple of options (at the moment 5). And when i  selected option 3, i don't see 1 and 2 anymore :S what does i have to change????

Comment: srr, didn't read well :P the line that i had to removve wass  listView.currentIndex = index; of the mousearea. Very much thanks for the piece of code :P

Comment: How can I access to selectedIndex from out of file that contain this code?

Answer (score 12):

For new users, there is a built in `ComboBox` in Qt5.3 **QtQuick.Controls** [ComboBox - Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html).

Example from Documentation:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ComboBox {
  id: combo
  editable: true
  model: ListModel {
   id: model
   ListElement { text: "Banana"; color: "Yellow" }
   ListElement { text: "Apple"; color: "Green" }
   ListElement { text: "Coconut"; color: "Brown" }
 }
 onAccepted: {
  if (combo.find(currentText) === -1) {
     model.append({text: editText})
     currentIndex = combo.find(editText)
   }
 }
}
```

Note: I had to post it as an answer, since the text is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using approaches with `ComboBoxStyle` (customization capabilities limited) and completely custom implementations, but they have a lot of limitations with `focus` management and `z-index` management.

I've end up with the implementation of `ComboBox` which consists of 2 parts: a header which you actually put somewhere and a dropdown component which you create dynamically. The latter consists of an `Item` covering everything (and intercepting mouse activity) and a dropdown which is carefully positioned below the header.

Code is pretty massive to included here so you can see details [in my blogpost with all the code](http://code.jamming.com.ua/ultimate-combobox-in-qml/)

Comment: Although it's shameless blog advertisement, It does seem that you've answered my question though. I'm not using qt anymore, so I can't test your code, but it looks promising. I do think however, that this could help somebody in the future with this problem. Therefore I won't flag your answer, because it has potential ;-)

Comment: @Mathlight Example code is quite big to be included here. Idea which can solve your problems is explained in my answer so if one has QML skill you can understand what I wrote (without going to my shamelessly advertised blog).

Answer (score 0):

If you targeting Nokia devices (Symbian or Meego), you could use high-level Qt Quick components. I believe `Menu` is something similar to html's `select`.

See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian/qml-menu.html or http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt-components/qt-components-meego-menu.html

Comment: i want to make it compatible ass posible for all platforms, so i will stick with this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Symbian, there is SelectionListItem and SelectionDialog:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian/qml-selectionlistitem.html

Comment: i want to make it compatible ass posible for all platforms, so i will stick with this one ;)