# How to hide a QML Window when it loses focus

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create a combo box with multiple selection using QML. Its dropdown will be a QML Window with the flag Qt.Popup so it will not have a title bar. The dropdown should disappear when the user clicks outside of it.

I tried the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window { id: mainWindow
    width: 200
    height: 200
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            dropdown.x = mainWindow.x + 50;
            dropdown.y = mainWindow.y + 50;
            dropdown.visible = true;
        }
    }

    Window { id: dropdown
        height: 200
        width: 200
        flags: Qt.Popup
        color: 'green'
        visible: false
        onVisibleChanged: {
            if (visible) {
                focusScope.focus = true;
                focusScope.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }

        FocusScope { id: focusScope
            focus: true
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }

            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if (!activeFocus) {
                    dropdown.visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work.

In the code above when the user clicks on the main window, a popup appears and if the user clicks on another window or on the title bar of the main window it should disappear but it doesn't do that.

If I import version 2.1 of QtQuick.Window instead of 2.0 I can put a 'onActiveChanged' handler (without getting an error) inside the dropdown Window but it is never called.

Maybe I would be able to do this using some C++ but I try to avoid that.

I use Qt 5.1.1 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Thank you.

*Update:* I switched to Qt 5.2 and solved the problem (see my answer below).

Comment: Please, provide more details. What are you trying to achieve? What error did you get?

Comment: Does `dropdown` disappear after following steps: click on the main window, then on `dropdown`, then on the main window title?

Comment: @johny Yes, it disappears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today I upgraded to Qt 5.2. In Qt 5.2 the following code works as I want:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window { id: mainWindow
    width: 200
    height: 200
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            dropdown.x = mainWindow.x + 50;
            dropdown.y = mainWindow.y + 50;
            dropdown.visible = true;
            dropdown.requestActivate();
        }
    }

    Window { id: dropdown
        height: 200
        width: 200
        flags: Qt.Popup
        color: 'green'
        visible: false
        onActiveChanged: {
            if (!active) {
                dropdown.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works because, in Qt 5.2, `QtQuick.Window 2.1` is specified [in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) as the latest version of that module and it gives me access to [`QWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html)'s [`activeChanged` signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html#active-prop) and [`requestActivate` slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html#requestActivate) ([QML `Window`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) is the equivalent of [`QQuickWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickwindow.html) in C++, which is a subclass of [`QWindow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Probably, if you change (in `onClicked` handler)

```
dropdown.visible = true;
```

to:

```
dropdown.flags = Qt.Window
dropdown.visible = true;
dropdown.flags = Qt.Popup
```

you will get necessary result.

There is a nice example of `DropDown`: [Qt QML dropdown list like in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634897/qt-qml-dropdown-list-like-in-html) without using another `Window`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I make the suggested change, the application behaves in a strange way. `dropdown` hides when it loses focus and its `flags` property changes its value to Qt.Popup after `dropdown` is shown, but it keeps its title bar, close button etc. To me, this looks like a bug. Also, thank you for the link. I think it will help me. I still want to use a Window, even if I have to work in C++ for this, because I think that only in this way the dropdown can extend beyond the size of the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Lost hours trying to bind to ActiveChanged. Found another solution

```
onActiveFocusItemChanged: {
    if (!activeFocusItem) {
        _.visible = false
    }
}
```