# QML Subwindow does not close as expected

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to implement a subwindow as a pop up that should disappear when the user clicks outside of it.  Following the example set by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444257/how-to-hide-a-qml-window-when-it-loses-focus), I came up with this:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        width: 20
        height: 20
        color: "green"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered: {
                console.log( "Entered" );
                menu.visible = true;
                menu.requestActivate();
            }
        }

        Window {
            id: menu
            width: 100
            height: 100
            x: win.x + block.width
            y: win.y + block.height

            flags: Qt.Popup
            color: "red"
            visible: false

            onActiveChanged: {
                console.log( "Pop up:", active );
                if ( !active ) {
                    visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    onActiveChanged: {
        console.log( "Main win:", active );
    }
}
```

However the popup does not disappear when clicked outside of, the debug output is:

```
// Main win opens
qml: Main win: true

// Green square entered
qml: Entered
qml: Main win: true
qml: Pop up: true

// Clicked outside of the pop up
qml: Pop up: true
qml: Main win: true
```

As you can see the main window does *not* lose focus when the pop up becomes active, so when the user clicks outside of it the overall focus does not change.  So how is this approach supposed to work!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found feels quite hackish, but it works, it's self-contained, and it's scalable.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        width: 20
        height: 20
        color: "green"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered: {
                menu.visible = true;
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: menu
            width: 100
            height: 100

            anchors.top: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.right

            color: "red"
            visible: false

            Loader {
                id: exitAreaLoader
                Component {
                    id: exitArea

                    MouseArea {
                        x: 0
                        y: 0
                        parent: menu.getRoot()
                        width: if ( parent !== null ) { return parent.width }
                        height: if ( parent !== null ) { return parent.height }

                        onPressed: {
                            var pnt = Qt.point( mouse.x - menu.parent.width,
                                                mouse.y - menu.parent.height );
                            if ( !menu.contains( pnt ) )
                            {
                                console.log( "Closing", pnt );
                                menu.visible = false;
                                exitAreaLoader.sourceComponent = undefined;
                            } else {
                                mouse.accepted = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            onVisibleChanged: {
                if ( visible ) {
                    console.log( "Opening" );
                    exitAreaLoader.sourceComponent = exitArea;
                }
            }

            function getRoot() {
                var par = parent;
                while ( par.parent !== null ) {
                    par = par.parent;
                }

                return par;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The general principle is that when the menu/popup/drop down is made visible a `Loader` creates a `MouseArea` as the most descendent child in the entire `QObject` tree (this guarantees that all mouse events within the window will be received by it).  However this means that mouse events that are destined for whatever the popup contains are also captured by the `MouseArea`, so we have to explicitly test for that and reject the event.

It's a real shame that there's not an official object for this, [one was requested years ago](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-15001) and it seems to have [adopted by Ubuntu](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.InverseMouseArea/), but that's not very useful for cross-platform development.